# Getting form element attribute values in cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I came from a symfony background. In symfony to get any form element attributes that symfony generates I would do something like form.username.vars.id , form.username.vars.full_name to get id, name attribute for that field.

I was wondering how I would do this in cakephp2. For example in cakephp:

```
 echo $this->Form->input('username');
```

would generate:

```
 <input type="text" required="required" id="UserUsername" value="admin" maxlength="50" name="data[User][username]">
```

I only want to get the id, name generated by cakephp so that I could use in javascript . How can I do this ? Are there any helpers to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The convention is consistent for naming these attributes.

- Name will always be `data[ModelName][field]`
- ID will always be `ModelNameField`

You can also choose the ID when you echo out the element:

```
echo $this->Form->input('username', array('id' => 'username'));
```

You can also change the name (you guess it, `'name' => 'name'`), however that could definitely mess with form processing in CakePHP.